# Unable to pass a variable from a javascript file to php file via URL

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a simple calculator program where the final answer should be displayed in a php file. I made the calculator part with javascript and need to display the output in php file. Below is my javascript code to transfer data via url:

```
window.location.href="result.php?answer="+this.total;
```

And below is my php code:

```
<div class="calculator-grid">
        <!--<input type="button" value="View" onclick="view()"><br>-->
        <div class="result-grid">
            <span id="equal">=</span>
            <span id="answer"<?php echo $_GET['answer']; ?>></span>
        </div>
```

The output div tag doesn't give any output and stays blank. In the console I get an error message as below:

```
GET http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=GCz71SnZwNTMry-Cd5vvWPl66eM5GuCpbXe1d7-SZqXoOLAnRJFHBx3RUIBEnCLkwQWGmNDSrvVNkys74RTQOx_57sHOch2--5bohP_U9Ic net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: There is a syntax error here somewhere `<span id="answer"<?php echo $_GET['answer']; ?>></span>` Let's assume `$_GET['answer']` is equal to `{answer}`, your code would produce something like `<span id="answer"{answer}></span>`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton oh it was a big blunder from me thank you